# Swift for-in loop dictionary experiment

Tags: dictionary, swift, control-flow, for-in-loop

I'm almost a complete programming beginner and I've started to go through a Swift ebook from Apple.

The things I read are pretty clear, but once you start to experiment things get tricky :).

I'm stuck with the experiment in the Control Flow section. Here is the initial code:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

var largest = 0
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
        }
    }
}

largest
```

And here is the task:

> Add another variable to keep track of which kind of number was the
>   largest, as well as what that largest number was.

As I understand, they want me to add up all the values in each number kind (get a total sum for Prime, Fibonacci and Square) and then compare the result to show the largest result.
But I can't figure out the syntax.

Can someone share any advice on how to tackle this experiment?
Maybe I'm not understanding the problem?

Comment: It seems to be asking you to simply record the type of the number that is the largest (you're already tracking what the largest number is, that's what the `largest` variable is for).

Comment: It's a duplicate-question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060604/for-loop-in-apple-swift/24060781#24060781

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They're just asking you to keep track of which number category the largest number belongs to:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largestkind = ""
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestkind = kind
        }
    }
}
largest
largestkind
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Could you also please help me understand the correct flow of events: 1. the code iterates through all the numbers in all the categories, 2. it finds the largest number, 3. it records the kind of the largest number. I'm I correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. As it goes through all the numbers it keeps reassigning values to largest/largestKind. For example it first sees 2 and assigns largest = 2, largestKind = "Prime". Then it sees 3 and since it's bigger it reassigns largest = 3, largestKind = "Prime".

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use closure to make the tasks simpler.

The `for` loop calculate the sum of each series.

The final reduce finds the series tuple that contains maximum number.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

var sums =  Array<(String, Int)>()
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    sums = sums + [(kind, numbers.reduce(0, +))]
}

let maxSeries = sums.reduce(("", Int.min), { $0.1 > $1.1 ? $0 : $1 })

println(sums)
println(maxSeries)
```

Comment: The task is to find the largest number. Not the sum.

Comment: @jewirth - To quote OP: "As I understand, they want me to add up all the values in each number kind (get a total sum for Prime, Fibonacci and Square) and then compare the result to show the largest result. But I can't figure out the syntax."

Comment: The OP misunderstood the actual task :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here it from playground using Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3.0

```
let interestingNumbers = [
"Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
"Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
"Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

let largest = interestingNumbers.map{$0.value}.flatMap{$0}.max()
print(largest)
```

Optional(25)